# Array becoming empty after receiving into controller with AJAX call

Tags: c#, jquery, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class named as SOMEOBJECT contains a list of name Extras.

Am trying to pass a data via AJAX call into my controller.
Within the data received by the MVC controller the array showing proper length but the entire data inside the array object is empty.

Is there any solution for this?

am passing object of class SOMEOBJECT via AJAX call is something like this:
I took it via F12 DEV tools FORM DATA

```
chk1Checked:false
chk2Checked:true
chk3Checked:true
Extras[0][id]:COMP1
Extras[0][itemType]:DROPDOWN
Extras[0][itemId]:111
Extras[0][itemValue]:EVAL1
Extras[1][id]:COMP2
Extras[1][itemType]:DROPDOWN
Extras[1][itemId]:112
Extras[1][itemValue]:EVAL2
```

Am able to see 'Extras' variable inside my controller with length of 2 but the inside data is NULL.

Comment: What is the signature of your controller? And show the models . If the model contains a property `Extras` and its type has a property named `id`, then it would need to be `Extras[0].id:COMP1`

Comment: ... and the JS code where the data is gathered and sent could also be of use.

Comment: Why downvote?
It's a valid question & we can see the relevant details.

What else do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

says you have the Extra class like this

```
public class Extra
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
    public string ItemValue { get; set; }
}
```

try retrieve that list with matched property's name ..

```
public ActionResult YourAction(List<Extra> extras, bool chk1Checked, //...
```

data object post via Ajax should looks like this

```
{
    "Extras": [{
        "Id": 1,
        "ItemId": 1,
        "ItemType": "foo",
        "ItemValue": "bar"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "ItemId": 2,
        "ItemType": "whatever",
        "ItemValue": ""
    }]
}
```

Comment: Then how will be the AJAX call should be... regarding data parameter??

Comment: I did created an extra dummy controller method and tried to pass 'List<Extra> extras'. But here also am getting the array with proper length and missing data.

<pre>
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DUMMYACTION", "CONTROLLERNAME")',
             dataType: "json",
             data: { Extras: EvalExtras() },
             type: "POST",
             success: function (result) {
                
             },
             error: function (result) {
              
             }
        }); 

<pre>

Comment: This wont work because the json data is not in the correct format

Comment: updated my answer, could you evaluate `EvalExtras()` result or log in browser console. json array should contains defined properties.

Comment: Yes am able to run the EvalExtras() and able to see my data array obejct.
Even I tried to pass extra string variable valled ExtrasSTR as JSON.stringify({'ExtrasSTR ':EvalOptionals()}).

And able to get the stringified JSON data but not the LIST<Extra>.